# Cannot access methods of pibase extension after upgrade to 6.2

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

We have an old custom-built plugin to manage a list of events, which does not work correctly after upgrading from TYPO3 4.5 to 6.2.

I believe I have done all the necessary migration steps, and the plugin seems to work in general. When I call just the page - without the GET-Parameters for the plugin, the main()-Action of the plugin is used correctly, i.e.

`https://<our-domain>/login/myaccount/events/events.html`

But any call to a method via the URL fails and I always end up with a 404. This URL worked in TYPO3 4.3+

`https://<our-domain>/login/myaccount/events/events.html?tx_<our-extension>_pi2[action]=newEvent`

I have searched and tried a lot of different things. I was wondering if the routing has changed so that the method is not called correctly.

How can I go about debugging this extension/plugin? How can I see what the GET-Parameter actually does to the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After receiving no answer here, I cross-posted the question to the German TYPO3-Forum. And got the [right hint by Jan](https://forum.typo3.org/index.php?t=msg&th=216121&goto=750294&#msg_750294):

[cHash](https://typo3.org/documentation/article/the-mysteries-of-chash-1) controls how the output of a plugin is cached or not. If not found, it was automatically redirecting to 404.